# create trigger AFTER INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the table schema ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d31c6a/19))

Is it possible to create a trigger on `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement?

Here's the query that allow users to update their like or dislike for a product.

Updated:

```
$vote = $_POST["vote"]);

$query .= "INSERT INTO `product_review` (ID,user,toyid,liketype) VALUES (1,Tom,1,1)";

if($vote == 'likes')
{
  $query .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE liketype='1'";
}

else 
{
  $query .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE liketype='0'";
}
```

After the  query, I want to add a trigger on table `reviews` to update like/dislike field.

I've tried

`CREATE TRIGGER 'after_like_update' AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON 'product_review'`

but the syntax is wrong.

The following trigger only works when a new row is inserted:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_like_update` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `product_review`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE toy a,
    (
     SELECT SUM( like_type =1 ) AS likes, SUM( like_type =0 ) AS dislikes
     FROM  `product_review` 
     WHERE post_id =  NEW.post_id
    )src
    SET a.likes = src.likes,
    a.dislikes = src.dislikes WHERE a.id =  NEW.post_id;

    END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE toy
    (`ID` int, `toy` varchar(21), `like` int ,`dislike` int)
;

INSERT INTO toy
    (`ID`,`toy`, `like`,`dislike`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ToyA', 2, 0),
    (2, 'ToyB',0 , 0),
    (3, 'ToyC', 0, 0),
    (4, 'ToyD', 1, 2),
    (5, 'ToyE', 0, 0),
    (6, 'ToyF', 0, 0),
    (7, 'ToyG',0, 1),
    (8, 'ToyH',0, 1),
    (9, 'ToyI', 0, 0)
;



CREATE TABLE product_review
    (`ID` int,`user` varchar(20), `toyid` varchar(21), `liketype` int)
;

INSERT INTO product_review
    (`ID`, `user`,`toyid`, `liketype`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom','1', 1),
    (2, 'Ben', '4',0),
    (3, 'Peter','1', 1),
    (4, 'May','4', 0),
    (5, 'May', '8',1),
    (6, 'Tom','7',0),
    (7, 'Paul','4', 1)
;
```

Comment: Triggers are only allowed per event but not grouped

Comment: Can I use two triggers one for insert, one for update?

Comment: @RedGiant: You certainly can.